# Adding buttons to UIToolBar Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have added a toolbar and then added 3 buttons to it programmatically. However, the 3 buttons are all cluttered to a corner. What i want to do is to have even spaces between the 3 buttons so the UI look decent.

How can I do this?

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:100];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(hideGender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button setTitle:@"Images" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

button.imageEdgeInsets= UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0, 50);

button.tag=0;


UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:100];

[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(hideSchool:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button2.tag=2;

button2.imageEdgeInsets= UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0, 50);

[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img22"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:100];

[button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(hideCar:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.tag=3;

button3.imageEdgeInsets= UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 0,50);

[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem0 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button] ;

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button2] ;

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button3] ;
```

UPDATE: I want to use only UIbutton

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:barBackButton]];
```

Now in `setItems` set the array of buttons. Suppose you want to put three buttons, then width of each button will be screenWidth/3 and text will be center-aligned. In this way, there is no over-riding of button.

Comment: I want to use UIButtons.